# Guest mode in Facebook chat is not working

Tags: facebook-chat

I connect Facebook Chat plugin to my web page. Plugin works correctly, but Guest mode is not available. There is no `Continue as Guest` button.

I enable Guest mode Facebook dashboard and I have no Country/Age restrictions.

How to fix this problem and enable `Continue as Guest` button in chat on my page?

Comment: What I would do is to make sure 'Guest model is enabled and if it doesn't help, try to Uninstall, clear cache and install this again. you can also follow this thread: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/fb-guest-chat-plugin-not-working/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer:

Facebook has stopped supporting the Guest mode.

The details are [here](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/311929848468629/).